# Какой механизм используется оповещения пользователя о процессе загрузки и обработки файла?

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework

Backend : *Django Rest API*
Frontend : *Vue.js*

Клиент загружает файл (файлы могут быть больших размеров). Файл загружается и дальше попадает в очередь *Rabbit MQ* для обработки.

Как оповещать пользователя о загрузке и обработке загруженного им файла (Preloader)?
К примеру применение *WebSokets* уместно.